# MvvmCross - Passing a string with IMvxNavigationService

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, parameter-passing, mvvmcross, navigationservice

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.iOS project that uses a web-api to gather data. However, I'm running into some problems trying to pass the user input from a textfield to the Tableview that gets the result from the api.

To do this I've followed the example on the [MvvmCross documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation).

The problem is that the input from the Textfield never reaches the 'Filter' property in my TableviewController's viewmodel. I think I'm not passing the string object correctly to my IMvxNavigationService when called.

To clarify, in my UserinputViewController I'm binding the textfield's text like so:

```
    [MvxFromStoryboard(StoryboardName = "Main")]
    public partial class SearchEventView : MvxViewController
    {
        public SearchEventView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SearchEventView, SearchEventViewModel> set = new MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SearchEventView, SearchEventViewModel>(this);

            set.Bind(btnSearch).To(vm => vm.SearchEventCommand);
            set.Bind(txtSearchFilter).For(s => s.Text).To(vm => vm.SearchFilter);
            set.Apply();
        }
      }
```

The Viewmodel linked to this ViewController looks like this:

```
public class SearchEventViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;  

    private string _searchFilter;

    public string SearchFilter
    {
        get { return _searchFilter; }
        set { _searchFilter = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchFilter); }
    }

    public SearchEventViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
    {
        this._navigationService = mvxNavigationService;
    }

    public IMvxCommand SearchEventCommand {
        get {
            return new MvxCommand<string>(SearchEvent);
        }
    }

    private async void SearchEvent(string filter)
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<EventListViewModel, string>(filter);
    }
}
```

And finally, TableviewController's viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class EventListViewModel : MvxViewModel<string>
{
    private readonly ITicketMasterService _ticketMasterService;
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    private List<Event> _events;

    public List<Event> Events
    {
        get { return _events; }
        set { _events = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Events); }
    }

    private string _filter;

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _filter; }
        set { _filter = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Filter); }
    }


    public EventListViewModel(ITicketMasterService ticketMasterService, IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
    {
        this._ticketMasterService = ticketMasterService;
        this._navigationService = mvxNavigationService;
    }

    public IMvxCommand EventDetailCommand {
        get {
            return new MvxCommand<Event>(EventDetail);
        }
    }

    private void EventDetail(Event detailEvent)
    {   
        _navigationService.Navigate<EventDetailViewModel, Event>(detailEvent);
    }

    public override void Prepare(string parameter)
    {
        this.Filter = parameter;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
        this.Events = await _ticketMasterService.GetEvents(Filter);
    }
}
```

Whenever trying to run, the string object 'parameter' in my TableviewController's Prepare function remains 'null' and I have no idea how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your command setup

```
new MvxCommand<string>(SearchEvent);
```

As this command is being bound to a standard UIButton. It will not pass through a parameter value of your filter but null instead. So the string parameter generic can be removed. Additionally, as you want to execute an asynchronous method I would suggest rather using `MvxAsyncCommand`

```
new MvxAsyncCommand(SearchEvent);
```

Then in terms of `SearchEvent` method you can remove the parameter. The value of filter is bound to your `SearchFilter` property. It is this property's value that you want to send as the navigation parameter.

```
private async Task SearchEvent()
{
    await _navigationService.Navigate<EventListViewModel, string>(SearchFilter);
}
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm! If it's not too much to ask could you clarify when you should use the parameter generic? In this same project I pass a single object from the resultList to a detailViewController in which it wouldn't work without it.

Comment: @K.Warrens sure, for a UIButton the default binding is [TouchUpInside](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Target/MvxUIControlTargetBinding.cs#L51) which will pass though a null to the command. While a TableViewSource allows binding to [SelectionChangedCommand](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/master/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Views/MvxBaseTableViewSource.cs#L49) which will pass through the ViewModel for the row selected. So they can be used any time that a command gets pasted an object. I hope that helps :)